# How to correct the extent of a raster?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.2, extents

How to correct the extent of a raster?

According to the metadata of the raster I downloaded, it should be (WGS84):

- North : 85.044
- South : -85.044
- East : 180
- West : -180

But this is the extend of the raster when I display it in ArcGIS:

[image]

Comment: "rebox" may be a useful search term.

Comment: It is sort of the same, it goes from ~0 to ~360 (whole Earth) but the extent is -180 to 180 (whole Earth) the difference is where the break sits. Where is your target area? Are you working around Greenwich? Note that negative coordinates in WGS would be a very rare thing to see; WGS84 uses the Greenwich prime meridian : http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/wgs-84/esriwkt/ so that's 0 and increases moving east.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In GRASS GIS it is as simple as defining the extent of your raster while setting up in the location wizard and importing the raster into the database.

If you do not use GRASS, you can try reprojecting it to your desired coordinate system in a blank ArcMap canvas.